# Creating a callback on javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been searching and either I don't understand or can't find anything that's relevant to my issue. Basically, I have a function

```
function Loading() {
    jQuery("#loading").fadeToggle(500);
}
```

And I want to be able to run something to the effect of

```
Loading(function() { });
```

Which executes the script in the function() {} when I want it to (within the function)

Comment: And when do you want it to execute ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pass a callback into Loading:

```
function Loading(callback) {
    jQuery("#loading").fadeToggle(500, callback);
}
```

As per the jQuery docs: [Jquery](http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/)

Comment: Hey Chris, thanks so much. Can I just ask one quick question before I mark it as the best answer. How can I make callback an optional field in this instance?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it'll be optional like that, if not you can change the fadeToggle line to: ```jQuery("#loading").fadeToggle(500, callback | jQuery.noop);```

Comment: @ChrisC `||`, not `|`

Comment: @Alnitak yep that's the one, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
function Loading(callback) {
    jQuery("#loading").fadeToggle(500,callback);
}

Loading(calloncomplete);

function calloncomplete() {
\\do something 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use done method

```
function Loading(callback) {
    jQuery("#loading").fadeToggle(500).done(callback);
}
```

Comment: You can't call `.done()` unless you've first called `.promise()` on the jQuery object.